# File is not being inserted when Community User Approves approval?

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to change the user context to system context / another user context in an approval action?

I have a community (experience site) where users can approve commissions. Once the commission is approved, a checkbox "Comission approved" is checked on the commission. Then a related record is generated containing the committed data and a PDF(generated via @future method) should be generated and attached. Everything works just fine internally.

The problem is that from the community the PDF is not generated, because there are some permissions missing. I think the missing permissions are on the email template which gets queried in the future method.

Now I don't want to change any permissions, I just want to change the context in which this whole process gets kickstarted. Or change something in the flow where the context can get switched so to say.

So in theory I had the following approaches:

- Change the actual approver right before it gets approved, so that the approval context is run by an internal SF user (but ProcessInstanceWorkItem doesn't support triggers so it doesn't feel right)
- At least run the future method in system context (it's already without sharing, but as it's called from a Trigger, it's run in user context). Sadly System.runAs is only available in tests.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Context cannot be changed from user to system. Ideally you should assign the correct permissions to the user.

As an alternate solution, you can simply schedule a batch from an admin user that runs at regular intervals, goes through the records and does the pdf generation job. Make sure to have a flag on the record to track that pdf generation is complete, so the batch does not picks them more than once.

Comment: Hey, the batch job is a great idea! I solved the error now. It was because I didn't specify the networkid

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Mark it as accepted so it will help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Don't know how 10 minutes after I post the question I find the answer randomly, after spending hours to solve it.

When you insert files from a community, you need to use set the "NetworkId" inside the contentversion. Documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

Full working code is now:

```
// Get your file data
User u = [SELECT IsActive,IsPortalEnabled,LastName FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion();
file.VersionData = body;
file.Title = fileName; 
file.ContentLocation= 's';
file.PathOnClient=fileName;
if(u.IsPortalEnabled) {
    Id networkId = [SELECT Id FROM Network LIMIT 1].Id;
    file.NetworkId = networkId;
}
insert file;
```